# AngularJS NgResource API call

Tags: angularjs, json, api, rest, get

So I'm currently working with $ngResouce. My api: api/Content/resource/user.post.failed returns the following:

```
{
  "user.post.failed": "Thing.."
}

app.factory('testResource', function ($resource) {
return $resource(apiurl + '/Content/resource/:resourcename', {}, {
    show: { method: 'GET', isArray: false, params: {resourcename: '@resourcename'} },
    update: { method: 'PUT', params: {id: '@id'} },
    delete: { method: 'DELETE', params: {id: '@id'} }
})
```

});

This is what I call in my controller

```
$scope.test = testResource.get({resourcename: 'test'});
```

The question is actually really simple; how do I get just the 'content part' so test. I'm now getting the whole JSON part back.

So the scope test is now: {"user.post.failed":"Thing.."}
And I want the scope to be just Thing.

Probably really simple, but I couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `$promise` property of the object to see errors:

```
$scope.test = testResource.get({resourcename: 'test'});

$scope.test.$promise.catch(function onReject(response) {
    console.log('ERROR: ',response.status);
    console.log(response);
});
```

---

> So the scope test is now: {"user.post.failed":"Thing.."} And I want the scope to be just Thing.

```
 console.log($scope.test["use.post.failed"]);
```

Use the *property accessor* syntax.

For more info see [MDN JavaScript Reference -- Property Accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

HTML

```
{{ test["use.post.failed"] }}
```

Comment: Marked this one as the answer. Since this answer gives some more info ;) Thanks both of you for answering.

Answer (score 0):

```
testResource.get({resourcename: 'test'}, function(data) {
    $scope.test = data['user.post.failed'];
})
```